# ¿Que tipo de archivo es y como lo puedo abrir?

Tags: android, json

Logré obtener el APK de una aplicación de Android, analizando los archivos de la aplicación, la mayoría de archivos tienen la terminación "Config.json", cuando abrí el archivo me aparecieron un montón de caracteres. Como el siguiente:

```
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
```

Traté de modificarlo con un editor de archivos `.json` y `.xml`, pero me aparece el error que no es un documento `.json`. *¿Qué solución me podrían dar?* Recuerden que es desde Android

Comment: Parece un archivo binario codificado en base64 (te das cuenta por los "==" de relleno al final). Lo que sea que tengan, una forma de saber que son es viendo como los procesa la aplicación.

Comment: Si se llama "Config.json" es un archivo tipo json, pero en este caso esta codificado, deberías agregar más información, como abriste el archivo .apk?